# Renaming the Istanbul coverage report xml file

Tags: istanbul

I am using coverageIstanbulReporter to generate code coverage report for my javascript project. The default output xml file is named as 'cobertura-coverage.xml'. I want to rename this file to something else. I can't find the configuration for this.

```
 coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'cobertura'],
      dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
  },
```

Answer (score 4):

It's hinted at in the [main readme of the project](https://github.com/mattlewis92/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter#configuration), but I couldn't find a direct instruction either. I found it by [searching all of Github in code](https://github.com/search?q=coverageIstanbulReporter%20report-config%20cobertura&type=Code), that's usually a good way to find out how other have used things. Which isn't always correct, or applicable, but it will point in the right direction.

You have to add `report-config` *and* the name of the report type. Like so:

```
coverageIstanbulReporter: {
    reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'cobertura'],
    dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
    fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    'report-config': {
        cobertura: {
            file: 'custom_file_name.xml'
        }
    },
},
```

Comment: Hi Rutger, how to add the "report-config" and where? Thanks very much.